# Booleans, CONSTANTS or mapping table for 'status'-like fields?

Tags: mysql, database-design, python

I am modelling a User table which needs to have the following information about the users:

- `is_active?`
- `is_detained?`
- `has_voluntarily_deactivated?`
- `is_temporarily_suspended?`

and so on...

Basically, these are `boolean` flags with `true` or `false`. So, I am considering few approaches other than `boolean` flags which are as follows:

1. Create a single `varchar` field with values like `'active'`, `'detained'`, `'deactivated'`, `'suspended'`, etc.
2. Create a `tinyint` field and map the integers to another table containing status strings
3. Create a `tinyint` field and map the integers in code itself using constants, such as `ACTIVE = 1`, `DETAINED = 2`, etc. Is Python's `enum` type the best solution to this?
4. Create a `tinyint` field and map the integers to status strings in an XML or JSON file

Which of the above 4 or the original `boolean` style approach is preferable, or if there could be a completely different approach or a modified version of the above approaches, please let me know?

Also, in my code, how should I call these fields, like:

- `if (user.status == 1)`, or something like
- `if (user.status == STATUS.ACTIVE)`, or
- `if (user.status == 'active')`

(I think this will depend on which approach I follow)

These `status` values are not limited and may be added, edited or removed in future. Request you to answer in a database agnostic way and the programming language that I am using is Python.

Thank you for your answers

Comment: As not all DBMSes support Boolean a datatype, *Database agnostic* would be a `status CHAR(1) NOT NULL CHECK (status in ('Y','N'))`, or a single byte INT (doesn't exist in Standard SQL, but most DBMSes support a variant) `CHECK (status in (0,1))`. Mapping could be a simple `CASE status WHEN 0 THEN 'active' ELSE 'NOT ACTIVE' END`in a view

Comment: But my question is should I be using `'Y'` or `'N'`, or `0` or `1` for each field, such as `active` status, `suspended` status, `detained` status or simply a single `status` field with integers `1`, `2`, `3` and so on... representing `active`, `suspended`, `detained` respectively? Please feel free to make any edits to my question if it needs some further understanding. Thank you :)

Comment: I would prefer one column per status.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you could use `ENUM` or `SET`, depending on whether the states are mutually exclusive.  That is, can it be both 'active' and 'detained'?

```
ENUM('active', 'detained', 'deactivated', 'suspended')
```

or

```
SET('active', 'detained', 'deactivated', 'suspended')
```